BLE Peripheral disconnection after sending a command in some Android phones
I am working on an android project which works with a smart ring using bluetooth. The problem is app and ring are working fine 95% of the Android phones. But in 5% of the phones getting disconnection problem in following scenario.

App sends command to ring to fetch data from a characteristic. Ring is recieving command properly, After ring sends its first transmission in response, ring is disconnecting with app.
As it is happening with only few android mobiles, I dont think its smart ring issue. I think we are missing something in bluetooth library setup in Android app. On the same mobiles, NRF Connect app(which is popular to test BLE Devices) also has same problem.

Can some one suggest me a fix for this whether fix should happen in ring side or app side?
I tried by changing connection interval, slave latency and supervisor timeout in ring side. But nothing worked. In App side used standard bluetooth library code.

Use the BTSnoop logs to find out what happens when an error occurs.
